# Can we apply the continuous mapping theorem to indicator functions?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, weak-convergence

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be a sequence of i.i.d random variables with zero mean and variance 1. Define $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ and $B^n(t)=\frac{S_{[nt]}}{\sqrt{n}}$ for $t\in[0,1]$. Donsker's theorem tells us that the process $B^n$ converges in distribution to a standard Brownian motion $B$ in $C[0,1]$. Let $t\in[0,1]$ and $\epsilon >0$. I would like to prove that:
$$\int_0^t {1}_{[0,\epsilon]}(B^n(s))ds\Rightarrow \int_0^t {1}_{[0,\epsilon]}(B(s))ds,$$
in  $C[0,1]$. I have thought about using the continuous mapping theorem where we basically have to show that the maps involved are measurable and almost surely continuous. To start with, the indicator function on $[0,\epsilon]$ is almost surely continuous as its discontinuities are simply located at $0$ and $\epsilon$, which ensures the weak convergence of the indicator functions. As for the integral mapping, I believe it is continuous everywhere, which enables us to conclude. However, I am not sure whether these arguments are sufficient and/or rigorous enough to prove the result? Any ideas or comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your process $B^n$ do not have paths in the space of continuous functions, but rather on the Skorohod space. Are you considering the smoothed process?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo I noticed that some versions of Donsker's theorem state weak convergence in $D[0,1]$ (as in the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donsker%27s_theorem) but others mention weak convergence in $C[0,1]$, such as on p3 of Khoshnevisan's notes (https://www.math.utah.edu/~davar/ps-pdf-files/donsker.pdf).

Comment: @DavideGiraudo But does this change anything to the fact of whether or not we can apply the continuous mapping theorem in this case? (I believe that if we were working in $D[0,1]$, the indicator function would still be continuous a.e and the integral map would still be continuous)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try to approximate the studied functional in the following way. For any integer $m$, define a continuous function $h_m$ on the unit interval such that $h_m=1$ on $[0,\varepsilon]$, $0$ on $[\varepsilon+1/m,1]$ and $0\leqslant h_m\leqslant 1$. Define for any positive integers $m$ and $n$ the random variables $$Y_{n,m}:=\int_0^th_m\left(B^n(s)\right)\mathrm ds\mbox{ and }  Y_n:=\int_0^t\mathbf 1\left(B^n(s)\in [0,\varepsilon\right)\mathrm ds.$$
Then we have:

1. for each integer $m$, $Y_{n,m}\to \int_0^th_m\left(B(s)\right)\mathrm ds$ in distribution as $n$ goes to infinity;
2. the convergence $\int_0^th_m\left(B(s)\right)\mathrm ds\to \int_0^t\mathbf 1\left(B(s)\right)\mathrm ds$ in distribution as $m$ goes to infinity;
3. the convergence 
   $$\lim_{m\to +\infty}\limsup_{n\to +\infty}\mathbb P\left(\left|Y_{n,m}-Y_m\right|    \gt\delta\right) =0$$
   for any positive $\delta$.

This is sufficient to deduce the wanted convergence (by Theorem 4.2 in Billingsley 1968). 
1. follows from the continuity of the functional $G_m\colon x\in C[0,1]\mapsto \int_0^th_m\left(x(s)\right)\mathrm ds$. 2. follows from the fact that for any $u\in[0,1]$, $h_m(u)\to \mathbf 1_{[0,\varepsilon]}(u)$ . For 3., note that by Markov's inequality, 
\begin{align}  \mathbb P\left(\left|Y_{n,m}-Y_m\right|    \gt\delta\right)&\leqslant 
\mathbb P\left(\int_0^t\left|h_m\left(B^n(s)\right)-\mathbf 1\left(B^n(s)\in [0,\varepsilon\right)\right|\mathrm ds \gt \delta\right)\\
&\leqslant \mathbb P\left(\int_0^t\mathbf 1\left(B^n(s)\in [\varepsilon,\varepsilon+1/m]\right)\mathrm ds \gt \delta\right)\\ 
&\leqslant \int_0^t\mathbb P\left(B^n(s)\in [\varepsilon,\varepsilon+1/m]\right)\mathrm ds/\delta.
\end{align}
We then conclude by dominated convergence.

Comment: Many thanks for your response. Just a couple of things. What is the idea behind using the functions $h_m$ if they are not continuous either? Can't we just use the fact that the functional $G_m\colon x\in C[0,1]\mapsto \int_0^t 1\left(x(s)\in[0,\epsilon]\right)\mathrm ds$ is continuous a.e?

Comment: And my other question is which theorem are you using to go from the convergence in 3 to the desired conclusion? Is there some sort of double limit interchange argument?

Comment: @user223935 i forgot to mention that $h_m$ has to be continuous, otherwise we may have problems with 2. The "double limit interchange argument" is proved in Billingsley (1968) and is a very useful result when we try to prove a convergence in distribution by approximation.

Comment: ok cool, but with the way you defined $h_m$ ($h_m=1$ on $[0,\varepsilon]$, $0$ on $[\varepsilon+1/m,1]$), it does not seem continuous, don't we need to link the points $\epsilon$ and $\epsilon+1/m$? Also do you have a more precise reference for Billingsley's result (page number of something), many thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can define $h_m$ in order to be piecewise linear for example. I mentioned the number of the theorem in the answer. If you have $Y_{n,m}\to X_m$ for each $m$, $X_m\to Y$ and $\lim_{m\to \infty}\limsup_{n\to +\infty}     P(|Y_{n,m}-Y_n|\gt \delta)=0$   then $Y_n\to Y$ (all the convergences are in distribution).

Comment: just one final thing, as Billingsley's theorem states that the assertion 3 needs to be proved with the uniform metric, can we just use the fact that $\sup_{t\in[0,1]}\int_0^t\mathbf 1\left(B^n(s)\in [\varepsilon,\varepsilon+1/m]\right)\mathrm ds\leq \int_0^1\mathbf 1\left(B^n(s)\in [\varepsilon,\varepsilon+1/m]\right)\mathrm ds$?

Comment: It depends of what you want. If you just want to study the convergence for a fixed $t$, then you deal with sequences of real valued random variables and there is no problem. If you study the convergence of the _process_ $\left(\int_0^t\mathbf 1\left(B^n(s)\in [0,\varepsilon\right)\mathrm ds,t\in[0,1]\right)$ in the space of continuous functions, then indeed you have to work with uniform norm.